# Nodejs Sequelize sqlite3 no such table

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

My models/index.js file:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const {Sequelize, Op, Model, DataTypes} = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.sequelize.define('Category', {
        name: {type: String, allowNull: false},
        url: {type: String, allowNull: false, unique: true},
    },  {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: true
    }
);


db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }); # it should create table
module.exports = db.sequelize.models;
```

console.log(db.sequelize.models) # output: {Category: Category}

If I make any queries to the model it throw an err:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: Category;

How can I insert the models in db?

Comment: Can you post an example query?

Comment: `console.log(db.sequelize.models) # output: {Category: Category}` no meanning `the category table` is exist in the db, you can check the sqlite file with SQLManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a migration script to create the table,

```
shell$ sequelize migration:create --name create-category-table
```

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Categories', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Categories');
  }
};
```

```
shell$ sequelize db:migrate
```

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize
This is working with sqlite, and, there are many tables